# MX Master continuously unpairing itself

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I have an issue with my Logitech MX Master mouse continuously fail to reconnect when I get back to my desk. I have to press the connect button on the bottom of the mouse and pair it. This is getting annoying as I have to do this on a daily basis. Is there any way to make the mouse pair once and not have to worry about it again?

Thanks!

[image: I only have one mouse...]

EDIT:

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) 
OS X 10.11.6 (Cannot update due to macOS issues with Airwatch)
Logitech Options 6.30.48 (shows no new options)
Mouse 11.00.0012
```

EDIT 2:
This is getting nuts

[image: Like rabbits...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what macOS version you're running, have you ensured that you have the latest version of the Logitech Control Centre installed?

The most recent update was only released a few weeks ago. You can read more or download it from [here](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/software/logitech-control-center-for-macintosh-os-x).

If the update and info doesn't help, report back with the version of macOS you're running and the model of your Mac.

**[EDIT]**

Since we've established your Mac supports Bluetooth Smart technology, which the MX Master needs if connecting via Bluetooth instead of USB, I see you have three options open to you:

1. contact [Logitech Support](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/contact) directly;
2. connect the MX Master via USB cable instead; and,
3. resolve the issue preventing your upgrade to macOS Sierra.

On the 3rd point, according to [this](http://blogs.air-watch.com/2016/09/macos-sierra-vmware-airwatch-support/#.WBWIv3dh3Qg) you should be fine to upgrade to macOS Sierra if using Airwatch. Perhaps it would be worth you asking a separate question about this? You may find resolving that also resolves your MX Master issue, since you'd be able to install the latest version of the Logitech Control Centre.

Comment: I cannot install the version of Logitech Control Center you suggested as it is only for 10.12.0. Let's see what happens when I apply the latest update to El Capitan.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, the latest version for your macOS. Sorry I wasn't clearer - but from the link I provided  you could access previous versions, so the latest that will run for you. Good luck - hope it helps!

Comment: Welp, I cannot upgrade to macOS yet. This mouse is almost a year old and I literally have paired the mouse nearly a 100 times. It's rather sad that Logitech does not offer drivers for 10.11.

Comment: Upgraded to Mojave and am not having this issue. Thanks @Manomeeth